# Ways to automate "downloading updates" from third party softwares

Tags: google-chrome, vlc, automatic-updates, third-party-cookies

I am trying to automate updates from third party software.

Let's say the software is google chrome. I want to check from my system if there is any new version of chrome made available. If yes, download that update.

Any ideas on how to scan such updates from different software (VLC, Chrome, Mozilla etc.) and download the same.